# Is to possible to use Ansible synchronize on two directories on target node?

Tags: ansible

Can I use the [synchronize](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/synchronize_module.html) module to synchronize two directories on the target node?

Default [synchronize](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/synchronize_module.html) is used to transfer files from the control machine to the target machine. Can it be configured to sync two directories on the target machine as well? How?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Something like this will do it:

```yaml
  - name: Syncs sources to target
    synchronize:
      src: '/my/origin/'
      dest: '/my/destination'
    delegate_to: "{{ inventory_hostname}}"
```

Key is the delegation to the target host itself.  You may need to play with the *become* option and, of course, see the other options from the module.